# Amazon SP-API POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Guys,
I'm trying to set some data about tracking and carriers into Amazon orders using SP-API, This is my xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A2Q8NNZCLEEE3</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>701-6891475-8035762</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentDate>2023-08-24T22:17:42+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>Estafeta</CarrierCode>
                <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>40727803439</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>B0CB242D3N</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </Item>
        </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

When I receive the feed response I have the next message:

"We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed."

I tried it all I can Imagine, but it doesnt work.

Do you guys have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

a) you are posting an XML  which is from the old outdated MWS  , the current is Selling Partner API which is Rest/Json based

b) your AmazonOrderItemCode is wrong, looks like you are using an ASIN
when it is a  14 digit decimal number
the value comes from field OrderItemId 31812312381232 /OrderItemId from the OrderXML

hth

Answer (score 0):

Use xsd to verify the xml before uploading it

```
<xsd:element name="AmazonOrderItemCode">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{1,64}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

[amzn-base.xsd](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/amzn-base.xsd)